# Subtract multiple strings from one record

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am novice to Postgres queries. I am trying to pull substring from each record of column based on specific set.
    Suppose, I substring from each record between keywords 'start' & 'end'. So the thing is it can be multiple occurrences of 'start' & 'end' in one record and need to extract what occurs between each set of 'start' & 'end' keywords.

[image]

Do we have possibility to achieve this with single query in Postgres, rather than creating a procedure? If yes, could you please help on this or re-direct me where I can find related information?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `/` always delimits the elements, you can use `string_to_array()` to convert the string into multiple elements and `unnest()` to turn the array into a result. You can then use `regexp_replace()` to get rid of the delimiters in the curly braces:

```
select d.id, regexp_replace(t.name, '{start}|{end}', '', 'g')
from the_able d
  cross join unnest(string_to_array(d.body,'/')) as t(name);
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/8863

Comment: This is just an example data. Data is not in same format as above. May have some other data between {end}/{start}. Main intention is to extract data between some specific keywords.

Comment: @Keen2Learn: then please post the **real** data. If you post made up-date you'll get wrong answers

Answer (score 0):

You achieve all this using regular expressions, and the PostgreSQL regex functions regexp_matches (to match content between your tags) and regexp_replace (to remove the tags):

```
with t(id,body) as (values 
                     (1, '{start}John{end}/{start}Jack{end}'),
                     (2, '{start}David{end}'),
                     (3, '{start}Ken{end}/{start}Kane{end}/{start}John{end}'))
select id, regexp_replace(
             (regexp_matches(body, '{start}.*?{end}', 'g'))[1],
             '^{start}|{end}$', '', 'g') matches
from t
```